# issue in id passing into function

Tags: javascript, spring

I cannot pass id into javascript onClick method. I use Spring framework and in the controller class, I send related id to jsp file like that:

```
    model.addAttribute("uploadid", uploadid);
```

Then, I have to send this uploadid to javascript onClick method. I try to do this operation like below:

```
<a href="#" onClick="uploadThumbnailClicked(\''+"${uploadid}"+'\')"><spring:message code="thumbnail.new"/></a>
```

But it does not work.

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function uploadThumbnailClicked(uploadid) {
        console.log(document.getElementById(uploadid));
    }
</script>
<a href="#" onClick="uploadThumbnailClicked('${uploadid}')">link</a>
<div id="test"></div>
```

In this case your controller sends (uploadid = 'test') to the JSP.